# using AWS Elastic search with VPC endpoint django haystack

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticsearch

I want to use AWS Elastic-search service with my django application which is running on EC2 instance.
For that I use the settings -

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
  'default': {
  'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch5_backend.Elasticsearch5SearchEngine',
  'URL': 'https://vpc-ES-CLUSTER.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:9200/',
  'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
  'INCLUDE_SPELLING':True,
  },
}
```

I am not even able to set the connection. Here I am getting this error -

> raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError((, 'Connection to vpc-ES-CLUSTER.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=10)')) caused by: ConnectTimeoutError((, 'Connection to vpc-ES-CLUSTER.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

I have updated the access policy to allow the user for edit and list, also in security group add the port 9200 TCP rule. How to connect ec2 with elastic search using VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working on 443 port, use

`'URL': 'https://vpc-ES-CLUSTER.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/',`

and in security groups add 443 open port.